# Starting and Stopping dedicated AWS instances using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking to start and stop my Amazon instances through Java. I have dedicated instances and do not create new instances on the fly for my needs.

I have read the AWS Java SDK documentation for starting and stopping the instances but I could only find RunInstancesRequest class which is used to launch a new instance.

Currently, I use the AWS CLI to start and stop the instances.

I am working on creating an Android/iOS app which can be used to start, stop and request status of my AWS instances

Answer (score 2):

Try these API references

**AWS Java SDK:** [StartInstancesRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/StartInstancesRequest.html) and [StopInstancesRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/StopInstancesRequest.html) 
**AWS Android SDK:** [StartInstancesRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/StartInstancesRequest.html) and [StopInstancesRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/StopInstancesRequest.html)
**AWS iOS SDK:** [StartInstancesRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSEC2StartInstancesRequest.html) and [StopInstancesRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSEC2StopInstancesRequest.html)

Comment: shame on me, I have been navigating through documentation all this while